# How to get permalink of a review/rating from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permalinks, facebook-page, review

We are implementing a review system in our app and pulling Yelp, Facebook reviews for certain businesses from their respective pages.

With Yelp a permalink is included in data for each review so that we link back the user to the Yelp page.

We want to do the same with Facebook (Single View that lists Yelp and Facebook reviews for the business - the only problem is we are unable to get the permalink for the review from Facebook [Graph API Data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/).

Found a Facebook Developer Community [question](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/171986814030055/) requesting the same (asked 4 months ago) but no answer till date.

Is there any way that a Facebook Page Review's permalink can be obtained?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don’t see the documentation mention any way to get such a link. Guess you can only try and figure out if they follow any specific format, that you might be able to re-create with the data you do get from the ratings object. (But then it could break at any time, if Facebook decides to change that format one day.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your time reading through docs. We did a workaround to construct the URL. Yes, it would break if Facebook changes the format. We will keep an eye on this feature. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling and digging through docs and forums, we couldn't find a way to get the link from API data.

As a workaround, the URL(permalink) can be constructed from review data.

```
https://facebook.com/ + review_object.id
```

So from graph API data, it would be - `open_graph_story.id`

**NOTE:** This approach would break if Facebook decides to change the URL structure in the future. So, be mindful of changes by Facebook.

Answer Credits: [Kalidas M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6379733/kalidas-muthusamy), my teammate.

Comment: With this, I would not worry too much about changes regarding URL structure. `facebook.com/{any_object_id}` works for most types of objects, usually it automatically redirects you to the “real” URL. I can hardly imagine _this_ getting broken - if the real URL changes, then Facebook will in all likelihood also update the redirect.

Comment: My initial hint was more regarding URLs with an actual “structure”, like if the review was currently available via something like `facebook.com/{pagename}/reviews/{review-id}` - that kind of format would be more likely to be changed at some point, so stuff like this should not be relied upon, unless explicitly documented somewhere.

Comment: That's true, custom structured URL apart from docs are always prone to changes.